# FB.Canvas.setSize is not officially supported

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, canvas, tabs

Currently I have two working apps developed with the Facebook javascript API. Both are housed in the tab, not the canvas. Today I went to check a few changes and get this message on the console:

"The method FB.Canvas.setSize is not officially supported by Facebook and access to it will soon be removed"

Any idea on what can be used to replace "setSize" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best replacement is [`FB.setAutoGrow`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/).

But I think that message might be an error, so I'm looking into it.

Comment: Hope Facebook fix that "error" or so. Meanwhile set setAutoGrow and stay watching about that. Thanks for your answer @ColmDoyle.

Comment: Confirmed this was a mistake. Should be fixed soon enough.